# Lack of a tag related to social media on Academia

Tags: discussion, tags

When one is asking a question related to social websites on Academia like the cases which are found by searching keywords like [Facebook](https://academia.stackexchange.com/search?q=facebook) with almost 85 results, [LinkedIn](https://academia.stackexchange.com/search?q=linkedin) with 53 results, etc. s/he has only [website](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/website) option to choose a suitable tag for the question which seems to be too broad for the purpose of the social websites and is not specific enough. There are also some other tags like [community](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/community) or [society](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/society) but none of which are so relevant to those question types.

Should a [social-website](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/social-website) (or an equivalent tag) be created on the Academia and if creating this tag is reasonable, what would be a good Tag-Excerpt for it?

---

**update and conclusion**
After a few answers are posted to this question with positive vote rate; now, a tag suggestion (including the tag title, tag excerpt and tag wiki) for [social-media](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/social-media) has been posted in [this answer](https://academia.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1146/15723).

Please post your suggestions and comments to that answer to improve the suggested tag title and excerpt.

Comment: Note that there *is* a [tag:facebook] tag. And of the 85 search results for "Facebook" there are actually only about [16 questions](http://academia.stackexchange.com/search?q=Facebook+closed%3A0), of which 7 mention Facebook only tangentially.

Comment: @ff524 what about other social websites like: [LinkedIn](http://academia.stackexchange.com/search?q=linkedin+closed%3A0), [ResearchGate](http://academia.stackexchange.com/search?q=researchgate+closed%3A0), [academia.edu](http://academia.stackexchange.com/search?q=academia.edu+closed%3A0), etc.

Comment: While this question may receive down votes suggesting people do not think this tag is needed, I would like to say this question represents an excellent example of how to ask/propose a new tag.

Comment: I would strongly recommend against a tag, and instead go the other direction:  have only a tag called "internet".  Let academia SE stay specific.

Comment: Please put your proposed excerpt in an answer instead of in the question, so that people can vote on it independently.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

**Tag Title Suggestion** suggested in [this answer](https://academia.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1139/15723) and [this comment](https://academia.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1135/lack-of-a-tag-related-to-social-media-on-academia/1147#comment4208_1136)

After a few answers are posted to this question with positive vote rate, it seems that the [social-media](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/social-media) is a good choice to be created.

---

**Tag Excerpt Suggestion** suggested in [this answer](https://academia.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1147/15723)

> Use of social media (e.g. Facebook, blogs, ResearchGate) by academics to engage with other academics or students and to disseminate their research.

---

**Tag Wiki Suggestion**

> Social media is a collaborative internet  website through which users (both administrators and visitors of the website) can exchange and share ideas and information such as academic topics.

Comment: I don't think this proposed excerpt reflects the kind of questions people ask about social media here, so it doesn't seem very helpful for deciding whether to apply the tag to a question.

Answer (score 6):

I agree that it may be good to have a related tag. How about [social-media](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/social-media) or maybe even better [web-presence](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/web-presence) (or [internet-presence](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/internet-presence))?

Comment: Does not `media` refer to other means too? I mean, media is also used for newspapers, tv, etc. We should find a tag specially used for Academic Social Websites.

Comment: @Parsa What are examples of social media which are not websites?

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft I checked [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Social_media) and I also think social-media seems to be a good tag.

Answer (score 5):

If we are going to have a [social-media](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/social-media) tag, I think the tag excerpt should describe social media in a way that reflects [the kinds of questions people ask about it here](https://academia.stackexchange.com/search?q=social%20media). For example:

> Use of social media (e.g. Facebook, blogs, ResearchGate) by academics to engage with other academics or students and to disseminate their research.

Comment: May be we put your suggestion as excerpt and my answer suggestion as the tag wiki. I edited my answer, please check it.

Comment: @EnthusiasticStudent Generally on meta, we put one proposal per answer so people can vote and comment on things separately. There's no reason to edit other answers into your question or answer; if you agree with an answer, just vote it up, then wait a little to see what others vote. (That way, if someone disagrees with my excerpt suggestion but agrees with your wiki suggestion, they can vote on each separately)

Answer (score -1):

I would strongly recommend against a tag, and instead go the other direction: have only a tag called "internet".

Let academia SE stay specific to larger academic issues.

Answer (score -5):

My preference would be to improve the tag wiki excerpt for [website](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/website) rather than create a new tag. For example, the [website](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/website) excerpt could be changed to:

> Websites for a research group, conference, project, or individual academic; social media and academic community sites like LinkedIn, Facebook, PubPeer and ResearchGate; or sites and blogs about academia and higher education.

This, because I find it ambiguous as to whether certain sites are "social". It's easy to say Facebook is social, but is a blog social? What about a class forum on an online LMS? In academia, there are many cases like this where one person might categorize a site as social and another person wouldn't.

Comment: I think your suggestion to excerpt edit of website is more practical. And, is there any need to merge existing tag for facebook on academia?

Comment: I guess where I think the line should be drawn here is _ownership_: are you responsible for the content and maintenance, or are you just a user of somebody else's site? There's enough of a difference there to make it worthwhile to keep them separate, I think.

Comment: @aeismail I don't think "social" implies that difference. And some kinds of websites can go both ways; you can be a reader of blogs about academia, and you can also write one. Is one "social" and the other not?

Comment: Perhaps "social" doesn't encapsulate the difference, but "website" becomes too expansive if it includes questions about self-run academic websites, external repositories, social sites, and everything in between.

Comment: As stated in the question, I also think that website tag is a little broad.

Comment: I would say the distinction between [tag:website] and [tag:social-media] is that the first refers to a unilateral communication channel (appropriate for, e.g., publication lists, contact details, presentation of research groups), while the latter refers specifically to bilateral channels. For example, a blog is a website as long as you only post content, but becomes social media once you regularly interact with your readers via comments.