# Should we create some community wiki questions on meta to help new "power users"

Tags: discussion

As users gain reputation new ["privileges"](https://academia.stackexchange.com/help/privileges) become available to them including [flagging posts](https://academia.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/flag-posts) (reputation of 15), [editing CWs](https://academia.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/edit-community-wiki) (reputation of 100), [creating tags](https://academia.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/create-tags) (reputation of 300), and [editing questions and answers](https://academia.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/edit) (reputation of 2000). An active new user can gain these privileges in a month or two. While the help center provides a general overview of the privileges, it doesn't provide any site specific instructions. Do we want to create some how-to question and answers on meta addressing these, or any other privileges, to help new users? We could tag them with something like [howto-privileges](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/howto-privileges) to make them easier to find.

For example, I think [Lack of a tag related to social media on Academia](https://academia.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1135/lack-of-a-tag-related-to-social-media-on-academia) is a great example of how to propose a new tag. I asked a question a while back about [editing](https://academia.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/823/minor-edits-of-other-peoples-questions) and there is a nice question from Charles about [flagging and down voting](https://academia.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/199/whats-the-difference-between-down-vote-vote-to-close-and-flag), but none of these are really how-tos about privileges.

Comment: I think that's a great idea!

Comment: I agree with Charles—but this is needs to be a community project, not a mod project!

Comment: I think the Frequently Asked Questions on Academia is not active. Such instructions could be viewed on similar FAQ pages too. For instance: "How should a new Tag proposed and then created?" and the answer comes next.

Comment: I think a good example of your suggestion is something like this which is on [Met.TeX on StackExchange](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com): [I've just been asked to write a minimal example, what is that?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) They have a [faq tag](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/faq) for such questions and answers. Also look at this question: [When is (and isn't) it acceptable to edit?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/340/when-is-and-isnt-it-acceptable-to-edit)

Comment: FYI, if and when these questions get created, you and the other mods can make them look all official by adding [the special `[faq]` tag](http://meta.academia.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/faq) that regular users can't use.